# represent value of array products in another array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array {

```
$e = Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 11 [2] => 2 ) Array ( [989.32] => 13 [77] => 11 [0.99] =>2 );
```

and i want to multiply each key by their values respectively and use the values to create another array. Anyone know how?
i've tried:

```
foreach($e as $y=>$z)
{$x= $y * $z;
$p=array();
array_push($p,$x);}
print_r($p);
```

but i got:

```
Array ( [0] => 1.98 )
```

Comment: Can you post your so far tried code ?

Comment: take `$p=array();` before foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One little change in your code:

```
$p=array();
foreach($e as $y=>$z)
{
$x= $y * $z;
array_push($p,$x);
}
print_r($p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$p=array();
foreach($e as $y=>$z){
   $x= $y * $z;
   array_push($p,$x);
}
print_r($p);
```

Put your `$p=array();` out side the loop

Answer (score 0):

I assume your array was multidimensional array. so try like this

```
$e = Array(Array ( "0" => 13 , "1" => 11 , "2" => 2 ), Array ( "989.32" => 13 , "77" => 11 , "0.99" => 2 ));
$result = array();
$i=0;
foreach($e as $values)
{
foreach($values as $key=>$value)
{
$result[$i]= $key * $value ;
$i++;
}
}

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/bJL9P)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will understand why:

```
<?php
    $e = array(...);
    $p = array();
    foreach ($e as $y => $z) {
        $x = $y * $z;
        array_push($p, $x);
    }
```

So as you can see, in your code, you overwrite $p each time so that you get the last multiplication `0.99 * 2 = 1.98`